# Android error trying to execute startActivity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add functionality to an action bar. When I hit the button, I want to go to another activity. I did it before and it worked it, but now I'm getting the following error:

```
12-27 17:22:48.218 1339-1350/? W/Binder:
    Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-27 17:22:48.218 1253-1416/? W/InputMethodManagerService:
    Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2082 uid 10056
```

This is the code:

```java
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.ajustes:
            return true;
        case R.id.modo_edicion:
            Intent intent = new Intent(ImagenesAlumnoActivity.this, ModoEdicionActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And this is the code from the activity that I want to show.

```java
 public class ModoEdicionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modo_edicion);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `ModoEdicionActivity` have you declared variables?

Comment: The problem is that ModoEdicionActivity extends AppCompatActivity. If I do this, it works: ModoEdicionActivity extends Activity.

Comment: @diogojme I'm been clear? I don't need variables for now. I only want to show the layout.

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` extends `Activity`, so I don't see why that would make any difference. Please update your post with a complete stack trace of the exception, because what you have shown so far does not appear to be problematic at all.

Comment: @Karakuri I post what you asked for. Thanks